# How do I add pub.TableName in front of my source when trying to export the table?

Tags: openedge, dbeaver

I am trying to simplify a process and was curious if there is a setting where I can add a "pub." in front of a table name in dbeaver?

It appears as below and it is causing an export error because it doesn't know the table without the "pub."

[image]

I am using a progress/openedge database.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is this Data Transfer tool? It's not familiar to me.

Comment: @jdpjamesp If you right qlick on the table you want you can import/export there.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see your second tag, and it wasn't clear from your request either. We're talking dbeaver. I'm not at all familiar with it, but I presume it's using an ODBC connection to the Progress database?

Comment: @jdpjamesp Sorry for not being clear myself. Correct it and odbc connection.

Comment: How much data are you trying to transfer? And where are you transferring it to? Another Progress database? Or a SQL one? There may be better ways to achieve this using Progress tools rather than ODBC. Getting data out of the database with ODBC is going to be pretty slow.

Comment: @jdpjamesp     It's another progress database. It would only be maybe 20-40 records. Per stardards when adding records for a customer we are supposed to add them through DBeaver using SQL. I just wanted to short cut it slightly. But I agree it will be slower. I'll have to look into a few progress tool options if it can be done faster a better another way.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer data from one Progress database to another, then it's definitely better to use the Data Administration tool than an ODBC connection. You could even write code to do it in the procedure editor assuming you have a license to execute code somewhere in the system.

Export:

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE("c:\tmp\dump.d"). 
FOR EACH mytable WHERE <somecriteria>:
  EXPORT mytable.
END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Import:

```
DEFINE BUFFER bmytable FOR mytable.
IMPORT FROM VALUE(c:\tmp\dump.d"). 
DO FOR bmytable TRANSACTION:
  REPEAT:
    CREATE bmytable.
    IMPORT bmytable.
  END.
END.
```

The code's written in the Chrome IDE, so not compile tested, or functionally tested, but it will give you the idea. You'll want to sort out error handling and so on as well, along with ensuring you don't get a blank record at the end (can happen).

You could even employ an ANT/PCT script to do the work for you. It's very simple in reality and can be automated easily.